# Draw someshapes in Panel without using Panel1_Paint() event

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, paint

I am drawing something, let us assume an image over the panel in Windows form.
I can able to draw i I follow the below steps:

1) added panel to the Form
2) used the below code:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(im, leftTop);
    }
```

Is this the only way to draw over the panel.

I have a plan to draw withoutusing this event 
I tried by the below code, results negative.

```
this.panel1.CreateGraphics().DrawImage(im, leftTop);
```

in both the case im is an Image.

.. can I able to draw. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can draw it, however if the `Paint` event is raised, the default stuff will be re-drawn and all the thing you have drawn will be covered/erased/cleared.

So to draw your image, the best approach is to add drawing code in `Paint` event handler as the first code you posted does.

Otherwise, you have to draw your image periodically which is not efficient, because we just need to re-draw it when we need. The system provides the `Paint` event to notify when we need to repaint the control (beside the default drawing).

Here is the way in which you use a timer to draw your image periodically, but this is not recommended, just for demonstrative purpose:

```
 Timer t = new Timer();
 t.Interval = 10;
 Graphics g = null;
 panel1.HandleCreated += (s,e) => {
   g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
 };
 t.Tick += (s,e) => {
    if(g == null) return;
    g.DrawImage(im,leftPoint);
 };
 //
 t.Start();
```

In fact, the `Paint` event is raised when the `WM_PAINT` is sent to your `Panel`, you can catch this message to draw the image instead of draw it when `Paint` is raised.

```
public class MyPanel : Panel {
  Graphics g;
  public MyPanel(){
     HandleCreated += (s,e) => {
       g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
     };
  }
  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m){
     base.WndProc(ref m);
     if(m.Msg == 0xf&&g!=null)//WM_PAINT = 0xf
        g.DrawImage(im,leftTop);
  }
  //.... suppose somehow you pass im and leftTop in...
}
```